# Javascript restart feature

Tags: javascript

So I got a personal website that has both a pause/resume and a mute button and I would like for the pause/resume button to change to "restart" video after the video has finished playing. Once the user presses restart, the video restarts. Any idea on howto implement this feature? Here's the code at the moment.

```
const video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    video.volume = 0.15;

    function pause_resume() {
      const button = document.getElementById("pause_resume_button");

      if (video.paused) {
        video.play()
        button.textContent = "pause video";
      } else {
        video.pause()
        button.textContent = "resume video";
      }
    }
    function mute_unmute() {
      const button = document.getElementById("mute_unmute_button");

      video.muted = !video.muted;
      button.textContent = video.muted ? "unmute video" : "mute video";
}
```

Comment: Why not just set `video.loop = true;` from the start?

Comment: Are you using a library for the video player? if so most would provide event handlers to handle these types of requrements.

Comment: I could do a loop but I'll rather have a manual restart button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event, something like this:

-- Using the `onended` event handler property:

```js
video.onended = () => {
  button.textContent = 'Restart';
  video.currentTime = 0;
}
```

-- Using `addEventListener()`

```js
video.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  button.textContent = 'Restart';
  video.currentTime = 0;
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble adding it. I tried this https://codepen.io/jollyfps/pen/XWjJGpg and it doesn't work.

Comment: @jollyr6 you need to provide a working snippet, in that example you have PHP instead of generated HTML

Comment: I have local .mp4 files that are being played within that php content. I don't know how to resemble the .mp4 to work on codepen. The PHP provided is just a random math.random calling the videos from playing 1-4. The javascript i needed help with relates to it.

Comment: I gave you an example on how to solve your issue, without a proper fiddle I can't do much more than this.